# Send lastmodified/Etag/Cache headers in restlet for GET request

Tags: restlet

I couldn't find simple example that sends lastmodified/Etag/Cache headers in restlet for GET requests.

Thanks

Comment: Just ran into this myself.  Found the answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015511/setting-etag-lastmodified-on-representation-sent-by-serverresource

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `RepresentationInfo` Class and it's associated member functions that can help you do this: http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/representation/RepresentationInfo.html

It has 4 primary methods get/set Tag/ModificationDate

You can directly call them from the `Representation` class since it's a subclass of `RepresentationInfo`

Comment: But how do you set them within a subclass of ServerResource where the representation is still to be negotiated ?

Comment: @koma - the representation IS negotiated when your method is called. A `Representation` argument is passed to your `@Get` method - that's where you'll be using this. I'm not sure what you are confused about - and boy that's a long while for the comment :)